# Is the matrix $A − 2I$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix with eigenvalues $1, 2, 3,$ and $4$. Is matrix $A − 2I_4$ invertible?

---

I tried to tackle this by constructing a matrix with eigenvalues $1, 2, 3,$ and $4$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$
Now,

$$A − 2I_4 =
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since the determinant of this matrix is $0$, it is not invertible. But this is a very specific case. How can I generalize it to all $4 \times 4$ matrices with eigenvalues $1, 2, 3,$ and $4$?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $2$ is an eigenvalue, then $A-2I$ is not invertible. This is because the roots of $det(A-\lambda I)$ are the eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: @Peter Can you please provide some rationale as to why?

Comment: Remember that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $\det(A-\lambda I)\equiv 0$.  Then, is $A-\lambda I$ invertible with that zero determinant?

Comment: Aha I see - since $Av = \lambda v$, therefore $v (A - \lambda) = 0$. This is not invertible and has a determinant of 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scalar $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ if and only if there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}$. That means that $(A-\lambda I_n)\mathbf{v}= A\mathbf{v}-\lambda\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

That, in turn, means that the matrix $A-\lambda I_n$ has nontrivial nullspace.

So $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A-\lambda I_n$ has nontrivial nullspace.

What do you know about the connection between the nullspace of a matrix and its invertibility?

Comment: A matrix is invertible if and only if its null space is trivial. Since this has a non-trivial nullspace, it is not invertible. Thank you!